# Change Named range EPPlus

Tags: c#, excel, epplus, named-ranges

I'm using EPPlus to populate an excel file, I have many pivot tables that refresh when the file is opened.

Their source is always one of the two sheets populated by my application.

The problem is that everytime I populate there is a different number of rows,
I tried using a named range in their source but when I change the range of the named range with EPPlus , it doesnt work.

```
   epplusWs.Workbook.Names["named_range"].Address = "data_sheet!$A$1:$H$" + row.ToString();
```

Comment: can you paste the code you are using to create your pivot tables?

Comment: I'm not using EPPlus to create them, I have a template with them created with the named range as the data source,

Comment: so what is the problem? you are updating the address of named range address and the updates are not taking affect?

Comment: Yes, I also tried a dynamic range using a formula but EPPlus gives an error when saving the file if there is a macro or dynamic range in the file.

Comment: Would something like this work? : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33282955/defining-a-table-rather-than-a-range-as-a-pivottable-cachesource/33312038#33312038

Comment: Are you missing a number after the $H$?

Comment: No,the number is in row.ToString(). I think EPPlus doesnt support changes in the named ranges or source of pivot tables.

Answer (score 1):

This is a late answer but you could add a new named ranged like this:

```
    ExcelNamedRange NR = new ExcelNamedRange("named_range", sheet: worksheet, nameSheet: worksheet, address: <your address string here>, index: 1);
    package.Workbook.Worksheets[1].Names.Add("named_range", NR);
```

Comment: just an fyi, this solution doesn't work any more since the version 5.1.2 - this constructor scope is now set to internal in this version, it is recommended to use Gilles Boisson way instead

Answer (score 1):

I find a way to edit an existing one :

```
var range = epplusWs.Workbook.Names[rangeName];
range.Address = "YourNewRange";
epplusWs.Workbook.Names.Remove(rangeName);
epplusWs.Workbook.Names.Add(rangeName, range);
```